# How to send a html message ( with image save by MS-WORD) throw Indy 10 with Delphi XE7?

Tags: html, email, delphi, ms-word, indy10

My problem was about displaying images of an e-mail into Outlook.
The e-mail is created by a DELPHI program with INDY 10 Components (the problem also exits with Microsoft OLE CDO.Message).

Here is how to create the e-mail:

- Create a MS Word file with OLE Word «CreateOleObject('Word.Application') » .
- Export the MS Word file to HTML format
- Modify the MS Word file in order to change the path of images (thanks to a parser)
- Create the e-mail with « TIdMessageBuilderHtml » of INDY10 (see
  previous message
- Send the e-mail

The e-mail and its images are correctly displayed onto an IPAD or an IPHONE but OUTLOOK 2013 does not display images.

I look for solutions on the Internet in order to display images but it does not work: images are always replaced by the rectangle and a red cross.
The problem does not come from INDY (or COM object) but it comes from the MS Word file saved to HTML.

There are several possibilities to export from Word to HTML : the solution is to choose « Filtered HTML », that is to say « wdFormatFilteredHTML = 10 » in DELPHI.
As a result, the e-mail and its images are correctly displayed by OUTLOOK 2013 (and IPAD, and IPHONE).

```
  .
```

Comment: You should delete your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681439/how-to-send-a-html-message-with-image-save-by-word-throw-indy-10-with-delphi).

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
HtmlFiles.Add(InfoImage.FileName);
```

To this instead:

```
HtmlFiles.Add(InfoImage.FileName, ExtractFileName(InfoImage.FileName));
```

Or this:

```
HtmlFiles.Add(InfoImage.FileName).ContentID := ExtractFileName(InfoImage.FileName);
```

You are changing the MSWord HTML to refer to an email attachment using a filename-based Content-ID, but you are not assigning that same Content-ID value to the actual attachment itself.  The `Add()` method takes a Content-ID as an optional input parameter to initialize the `TIdMessageBuilderAttachment.ContentID` property:

```
function TIdMessageBuilderAttachments.Add(const AFileName: String;
  const AContentID: String = ''): TIdMessageBuilderAttachment;
```

Comment: Thank you Remy Lebeau, I do the modification of my code , but the image is not on the email ( the red cross is on the mail .

Comment: But this  modification  has changed something in the mail , with the previous version there is a "paper clip" on the mail , but it's impossible to see the file .... With the last version there is not a "paper clip" on the mail .

Comment: Remy, perhaps, it will be interesting to modify the page of "New HTML Message Builder class". Because in this page the “HtmlFiles” use only one parameter and the variable “subject” don’t exist in “TIdMessageBuilderHtml”.

Comment: @JPERE: The disappearing paper clip is actually a good thing, because embedded images should not be shown as downloadable attachments, so they should not trigger the paper clip to appear. However, the fact that the image is still not visible means something is still wrong with the email. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34698255/edit) to include the actual email data that `TIdMessage` is generating (you can use one of the `TIdMessage.SaveTo...()` methods for that).

Comment: @JPERE: And yes, the blog post is a little dated, as there have been some changes to `TIdMessageBuilderHTML` after the post was written.